# File listed twice in rpm spec file

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, rpm-spec

The files section of my spec-file looks like this:

```
%files
%{prefix}/htdocs/
%config %{prefix}/htdocs/share/settings/config.inc.php
```

Now, since the config file is already included in the `%{prefix}/htdocs/` line I get the warning 'File listed twice'.

One way around would be, to list every single file within `%{prefix}/htdocs/`, except the config file.

But my question is: Is there a better way around this issue, than listing all files?

Comment: That's not where config files go regardless.

Comment: There's no other way (and you should not keep your config in htdocs/share ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. RPM is quite oldschool software, but works fine :-)

But you can use globs too:

```
%files
%{prefix}/htdocs/*.png
%{prefix}/htdocs/*.html
```

etc.

This will enable you to include all the rest without some other files you do not want there. That's the way how RPM packagers do it usually.